# Should I create zone for each domain that I want to host on my server

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, iis, vps, web-hosting

I'm setting up a web hosting on my VPS, I want to host several websites on my vps, I have two domains, domain1.com and domain2.com and a website for each hosted on iis, I know that I should add these host names to my dns. I have a zone named domain1.com, when I want to add domain2.com as new host it will automatically set FQDN to domain2.com.domain1.com
How should I config my DNS?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate zone for each domain.

Here are [some instructions from one web host on how to do it](https://library.linode.com/dns-manager#sph_hosting-multiple-domains-on-a-single-server).  The process should be similar on any web host.

> To host multiple domain names on a single server, create a separate domain zone for each domain name...  At a minimum, you'll need an A record for each domain name pointing to the server's IP address.

Comment: But if I create a zone for each domain, is it possible to set each domain's name server to one name server like ns1.mydomain.com?

Comment: Your zones can all be hosted on the same domain name server.